Understanding CascadingValue IsFixed in Blazor Server
I have declared two <CascadingValue> component in my razor, which are passing same type(int) of value to the child component, one is declared with the Name attribute.
Counter.razor
    <h1>Counter</h1>
    
    <p role="status">Current count: @IncrementCounter</p>
    <p role="status">Current count fixed: @IncrementCounterFixed</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

    <p><b>Cascading Parameter</b></p>
    <CascadingValue Value="@IncrementCounter">
       <CascadingValue Value="@IncrementCounterFixed" Name="FixedCascade" IsFixed="true">
          <CascadingChild>
          </CascadingChild>
       </CascadingValue>
    </CascadingValue>
    
    @code 
    {
        public int IncrementCounter { get; set; }
    
        public int IncrementCounterFixed { get; set; }
    
        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            IncrementCounterFixed = 5;
        }
        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            IncrementCounter++;
            IncrementCounterFixed++;
        }
    }

CascadingChild.razor
<div>
    <p>Cascading value: @IncrementCounter</p>
    <p>Cascading value Fixed: @IncrementCounterFixed</p>
</div>

@code 
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public int IncrementCounter { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "FixedCascade")]
    public int IncrementCounterFixed { get; set; }
}

After clicking the Click Me button, the fixed value is not changing first time, but in the second click it gets changed to '6' and from the second click it keep on changing the value of the fixed property IncrementCounterFixed value.
But if i use the single <CascadingValue> component with IsFixed="true" attribute, the IncrementCounterFixed value is not changing, if the value is incremented in the Parent razor.
First click output:

Second click output:

Clarify me here how this works,
Thanks in advance.


Clarify me here how this works


The button click always causes a re-render of the parent component.

The CascadingChild component has no (normal) parameters so it would not normally update in a re-render. This is an optimization, avoiding unnecessary renders.

But a CascadingValue without IsFixed instructs Blazor to perform change-tracking and re-render the child on a change. Turning  IsFixed On (when possible) is an optimization.

The outer (non-IsFixed) CascadingValue will cause the child to update on each click. The inner value can 'hich-hike' along. But apparently the ordering is important here, that's why the displayed value is one step behind.


IsFixed limits the triggering of update renders but it does not change the passing of the value. When the child re-renders for any other reason you will see the latest value from the parent.
There are a few things you can do to examine this further:

swap the two <CascadingValue ... > elements. When the outer one is IsFixed then both values will update immediately.

use two separate child components. The outputs will be more deterministic and independent.



Hai @HenkHolterman, Thanks for detailed explanation, i tried the two scenarios you have mentioned above. The first one updates the both value immediately in the Child component. The second one, it works as expected like non-IsFixed CascadingValue is changing and IsFixed value is not changing. But i still don't understand properly that why the IsFixed value is changing if i use Single Child component with Two Cascading wrapped in it.

Your Point ''IsFixed limits the triggering of update renders but it does not change the passing of the value. When the child re-renders for any other reason you will see the latest value from the parent.'' Why am i seeing the new value from the parent even it is Fixed?

The value is not really fixed. The IsFixed property just tells Blazor assume it does not change and to be less trigger happy to start a  re-render.
